# CrossPagePostback : Previous Page's title not being shown in the second page

Tags: c#, asp.net

I had added `PostBackUrl="~/Default2.aspx"` in button control (in my first page).And in the second page I added `<%@ PreviousPageType VirtualPath="~/Default.aspx" %>` to my webform.

The second page is showing the text I entered in my previous page's textbox but it's not showing the title of previous page. What can be the issue?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class Default2 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (PreviousPage != null) 
        {
            Label1.Text = "you came from a page titled" + PreviousPage.Title.ToString();
            Label1.Text += "<br/>"+"you typed in"+PreviousPage.property;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You may need to add runat="server" to your head tag. Please show us the rest of your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `Title="YOUR TITLE"` as shown to Page tag in your Default.Aspx

```
<%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.master" AutoEventWireup="true"
        CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="ListDrop._Default" %>
```